# R Quanteda Filtering, counting and grouping features from a Customized dictionary

Tags: r, text-mining, quanteda

I have the following data set:

```
library(quanteda)
library(quanteda.textstats)

df_test<-c("I find water to be so healthy and refreshing",
           "Nothing like a freshly made burguer to make me feel good",
           "I dislike sugar in the morning it tastes horrible",
           "A nice burguer is always crispy and spicy",
           "It is beyond me to dare to drink soda it's just gross too much sugar",
           "Yes I will have a hot burguer anytime is so cheap and tasty")
```

I want to be able to built a Customized dictionary so that I can
classify words/tokens into two categories "Negative" and "Positive"
after that I want to filter by the most frequent words/tokens and plot
the positive and negative words associated with them

This is my dictionary

```
dict_custom <- dictionary(list(positive = c("healthy", "refreshing", "good", "crispy", 
                                      "spicy", "cheap", "tasty"),
                               negative=c("horrible","gross")))
```

What are some of the most frequent tokens?

```
> tok_df<-corpus(df_test) %>% tokens(remove_punct=TRUE) %>% tokens_remove(stopwords("en"))
> 
> tok_df %>% dfm() %>% 
+   textstat_frequency(5)  
  feature frequency rank docfreq group
1 burguer         3    1       3   all
2   sugar         2    2       2   all
3    find         1    3       1   all
4   water         1    3       1   all
5 healthy         1    3       1   all
```

I want to choose burger and get all the positive and negative words (after using my dictionary) and count the number of times they appear also perhaps create a word_cloud

I'm using this code:

```
> tokens_lookup(tok_df,dictionary = dict_custom) %>% 
+   dfm()
Document-feature matrix of: 6 documents, 2 features (50.00% sparse) and 0 docvars.
       features
docs    positive negative
  text1        2        0
  text2        1        0
  text3        0        1
  text4        2        0
  text5        0        1
  text6        2        0
```

but instead of words I get the count of positive and negative tokens per document.

My desired output will contain a matrix/dfm like object filter by burger with all of the negative and positive tokens (crispy, healthy, gross, ect) instead of the count of neg and pos tokens by document (that I do not want).

By the way, what if I want to instead of creating a neg and positive words, rather assign a numeric value lets say gross=-5 and crispy=5 how can I join and merge my tokens with this kind of dictionary so that I afterwards can summarize the numeric output?

Comment: That's not my vibe I like to be a lot more kind and open this is a human being going trhough some coding situations... and I belive that SO should be more open to that and cultivate kindness and love

Comment: It's been discussed _ad nauseum_ on Meta Stack Overflow - feel free to post again on the matter if you want to change policy (I think it would be a waste of time, but I won't stop you). But, for now, succinctness is required.

Comment: A good place to start reading on this topic [might be here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-like-greetings-signatures-thanks-etc-when-editin), then explore related items from the sidebar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is using the ability of `tokens_select()` to filter on dictionaries. By indexing each key separately - below, using `lapply` - then you can create a list of dfm objects whose features are the value matches for each key.

```r
library("quanteda")
#> Package version: 3.2.4
#> Unicode version: 14.0
#> ICU version: 70.1
#> Parallel computing: 10 of 10 threads used.
#> See https://quanteda.io for tutorials and examples.
library("quanteda.textstats")

df_test <- c("I find water to be so healthy and refreshing",
             "Nothing like a freshly made burguer to make me feel good",
             "I dislike sugar in the morning it tastes horrible",
             "A nice burguer is always crispy and spicy",
             "It is beyond me to dare to drink soda it's just gross too much sugar",
             "Yes I will have a hot burguer anytime is so cheap and tasty")

dict_custom <- dictionary(list(positive = c("healthy", "refreshing", "good", "crispy", 
                                            "spicy", "cheap", "tasty"),
                               negative = c("horrible","gross")))

toks <- tokens(df_test)

dfm_list <- lapply(
    names(dict_custom), 
    function(x) {
        tokens_select(toks, dict_custom[x]) |>
            dfm()
    }
)
names(dfm_list) <- names(dict_custom)
```

Now you have a list of dfm objects, named by your dictionary keys, which you can then get frequencies for, or wordclouds, etc.

```r
dfm_list
#> $positive
#> Document-feature matrix of: 6 documents, 7 features (83.33% sparse) and 0 docvars.
#>        features
#> docs    healthy refreshing good crispy spicy cheap tasty
#>   text1       1          1    0      0     0     0     0
#>   text2       0          0    1      0     0     0     0
#>   text3       0          0    0      0     0     0     0
#>   text4       0          0    0      1     1     0     0
#>   text5       0          0    0      0     0     0     0
#>   text6       0          0    0      0     0     1     1
#> 
#> $negative
#> Document-feature matrix of: 6 documents, 2 features (83.33% sparse) and 0 docvars.
#>        features
#> docs    horrible gross
#>   text1        0     0
#>   text2        0     0
#>   text3        1     0
#>   text4        0     0
#>   text5        0     1
#>   text6        0     0
```

Frequencies:

```r
lapply(dfm_list, textstat_frequency)
#> $positive
#>      feature frequency rank docfreq group
#> 1    healthy         1    1       1   all
#> 2 refreshing         1    1       1   all
#> 3       good         1    1       1   all
#> 4     crispy         1    1       1   all
#> 5      spicy         1    1       1   all
#> 6      cheap         1    1       1   all
#> 7      tasty         1    1       1   all
#> 
#> $negative
#>    feature frequency rank docfreq group
#> 1 horrible         1    1       1   all
#> 2    gross         1    1       1   all
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much Professor Ken I am in tears you are such a huge inspiration to me and I have learned so much using your awesome quanteda package thank you for taking the time and helping me out thank you so so so much

Comment: No need for tears! Glad I could help.